# Is it ok to run a virtual server (Virtualbox) with webroot within a shared directory with the host OS?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, apache2, webserver

As everything is a little bit slower through a VM I thought I would try and put my project's webroot in a directory that is shared between the client (ubuntu 14.04) and the host (Windows 8.1). The idea is so that I can use the Symfony2 framework on the Windows host using PhpStorm and access the projects thorugh `localhost:8000` for example.

It seems to be working fine however I wanted to check if this is the right way to go about it (Virtualbox's shared drives appear on Ubuntu under `/media` so I'm wondering if it's not such a good idea?)?:

My shared directory on Ubuntu is:

```
/media/<sf_share>/dbconnect_project1.php
                  dbconnect_project2.php
                  <project1>/app
                            /bin
                            /src
                            /vendor
                            /web
                  <project2>/app
                            /bin
                            /src
                            /vendor
                            /web
```